# how to vertically align two items on top of each other using html and css

Tags: html, css

I am trying to put two images on top of each other and make them align properly to form a house shaped object. One of the images is a square and the other one is a triangle. The triangle has to be on top and the square has to be at the bottom.

This is the HTML code:

```
<div class="heading">
    <h2><span class="bold_text">RENT</span><span class="light_text">HOMES</span></h2>
    <div class="house">
        <img src="./img/house_top.svg" alt="house top">
        <img src="./img/house_bottom.svg" alt="house bottom">                        
    </div>
</div>
```

This is the CSS code:
`.heading {
display: flex;
}

```
.heading .house {
    display: grid;
    height: 25px;
    width: auto;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    gap: 0;
}`
```

This is what I am trying to achieve:
[figma picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XLUDM.png)

I used "grid" to align the images on top of each other. And I also set the "padding" and "margin" to 0. But still there is space between the two images and they are not vertically aligned in a straight line. This is how it looks like right now.
[my code so far](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lqBqr.png)

Code for the triangle SVG image:

> ```
> <svg width="33" height="24" viewBox="0 0 33 24" fill="none" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
> <g filter="url(#filter0_d_174_86)">
> <path d="M16.5 0L28.1913 15.75H4.80866L16.5 0Z" fill="#D9D9D9"/>
> <path d="M5.80251 15.25L16.5 0.838871L27.1975 15.25H5.80251Z" stroke="#475C46"/>
> </g>
> <defs>
> <filter id="filter0_d_174_86" x="0.808594" y="0" width="31.3828" height="23.75" filterUnits="userSpaceOnUse"
> color-interpolation-filters="sRGB">
> <feFlood flood-opacity="0" result="BackgroundImageFix"/>
> <feColorMatrix in="SourceAlpha" type="matrix" values="0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 127 0" result="hardAlpha"/>
> <feOffset dy="4"/>
> <feGaussianBlur stdDeviation="2"/>
> <feComposite in2="hardAlpha" operator="out"/>
> <feColorMatrix type="matrix" values="0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0.25 0"/>
> <feBlend mode="normal" in2="BackgroundImageFix" result="effect1_dropShadow_174_86"/>
> <feBlend mode="normal" in="SourceGraphic" in2="effect1_dropShadow_174_86" result="shape"/>
> </filter>
> </defs>
> </svg>
> ```

Code for the square SVG image:

> ```
> <svg width="29" height="30" viewBox="0 0 29 30" fill="none" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
> <g filter="url(#filter0_d_174_87)">
> <rect x="4" width="21" height="22" fill="#D9D9D9"/>
> <rect x="4.5" y="0.5" width="20" height="21" stroke="#475C46"/>
> </g>
> <defs>
> <filter id="filter0_d_174_87" x="0" y="0" width="29" height="30" filterUnits="userSpaceOnUse" color-interpolation-filters="sRGB">
> <feFlood flood-opacity="0" result="BackgroundImageFix"/>
> <feColorMatrix in="SourceAlpha" type="matrix" values="0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 127 0" result="hardAlpha"/>
> <feOffset dy="4"/>
> <feGaussianBlur stdDeviation="2"/>
> <feComposite in2="hardAlpha" operator="out"/>
> <feColorMatrix type="matrix" values="0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0.25 0"/>
> <feBlend mode="normal" in2="BackgroundImageFix" result="effect1_dropShadow_174_87"/>
> <feBlend mode="normal" in="SourceGraphic" in2="effect1_dropShadow_174_87" result="shape"/>
> </filter>
> </defs>
> </svg>
> ```

Comment: Add the code for the two SVG images as well, please. Open the SVG file in a text editor, then copy-paste everything into a new code block in this question.

Comment: Added the code for the SVG images.

Comment: But why are you splitting/rebuilding the figma logo at all? You could easily use the figma logo as a single "logo.svg." Placing and resizing the logo in your HTML should be way easier.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This snippet illustrates the problem. I’ve added borders around the images so we can see their limits. Note the drop shadows on those images. So the images are larger than the shapes, in order to fit those drop shadows. (I’ve also used a flexbox container, rather than a grid.)

[image]

```css
.heading {
  display: flex;
  gap: 1em;
  align-items: end;
}

.heading h2 {
  margin: 0;
}

.heading .house {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
}

.heading .house svg {
  border: 1px solid red;
}
```

```html
<div class="heading">
  <h2><span class="bold_text">RENT</span><span class="light_text">HOMES</span></h2>
  <div class="house">
    <svg width="33" height="24" viewBox="0 0 33 24" fill="none" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
      <defs>
        <filter id="filter0_d_174_86" x="0.808594" y="0" width="31.3828" height="23.75" filterUnits="userSpaceOnUse"
        color-interpolation-filters="sRGB">
          <feFlood flood-opacity="0" result="BackgroundImageFix"/>
          <feColorMatrix in="SourceAlpha" type="matrix" values="0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 127 0" result="hardAlpha"/>
          <feOffset dy="4"/>
          <feGaussianBlur stdDeviation="2"/>
          <feComposite in2="hardAlpha" operator="out"/>
          <feColorMatrix type="matrix" values="0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0.25 0"/>
          <feBlend mode="normal" in2="BackgroundImageFix" result="effect1_dropShadow_174_86"/>
          <feBlend mode="normal" in="SourceGraphic" in2="effect1_dropShadow_174_86" result="shape"/>
        </filter>
      </defs>
      <g filter="url(#filter0_d_174_86)">
        <path d="M16.5 0L28.1913 15.75H4.80866L16.5 0Z" fill="#D9D9D9"/>
        <path d="M5.80251 15.25L16.5 0.838871L27.1975 15.25H5.80251Z" stroke="#475C46"/>
      </g>
    </svg>
    <svg width="29" height="30" viewBox="0 0 29 30" fill="none" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
      <defs>
        <filter id="filter0_d_174_87" x="0" y="0" width="29" height="30" filterUnits="userSpaceOnUse" color-interpolation-filters="sRGB">
          <feFlood flood-opacity="0" result="BackgroundImageFix"/>
          <feColorMatrix in="SourceAlpha" type="matrix" values="0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 127 0" result="hardAlpha"/>
          <feOffset dy="4"/>
          <feGaussianBlur stdDeviation="2"/>
          <feComposite in2="hardAlpha" operator="out"/>
          <feColorMatrix type="matrix" values="0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0.25 0"/>
          <feBlend mode="normal" in2="BackgroundImageFix" result="effect1_dropShadow_174_87"/>
          <feBlend mode="normal" in="SourceGraphic" in2="effect1_dropShadow_174_87" result="shape"/>
        </filter>
      </defs>
      <g filter="url(#filter0_d_174_87)">
        <rect x="4" width="21" height="22" fill="#D9D9D9"/>
        <rect x="4.5" y="0.5" width="20" height="21" stroke="#475C46"/>
      </g>
    </svg>
  </div>
</div>
```

So we need to adjust the positions. First, setting `align-items: center` on the flex container will get them to align horizontally. Then use `position: relative` and adjust the `top` value of each image until you get the alignment looking nice.

[image]

```css
.heading {
  display: flex;
  gap: 1em;
  align-items: end;
}

.heading h2 {
  margin: 0;
}

.heading .house {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  align-items: center;
}

.heading .house svg:first-child {
  position: relative;
  top: 13px;
}

.heading .house svg:last-child {
  position: relative;
  top: 4px;
}
```

```html
<div class="heading">
  <h2><span class="bold_text">RENT</span><span class="light_text">HOMES</span></h2>
  <div class="house">
    <svg width="33" height="24" viewBox="0 0 33 24" fill="none" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
      <defs>
        <filter id="filter0_d_174_86" x="0.808594" y="0" width="31.3828" height="23.75" filterUnits="userSpaceOnUse"
        color-interpolation-filters="sRGB">
          <feFlood flood-opacity="0" result="BackgroundImageFix"/>
          <feColorMatrix in="SourceAlpha" type="matrix" values="0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 127 0" result="hardAlpha"/>
          <feOffset dy="4"/>
          <feGaussianBlur stdDeviation="2"/>
          <feComposite in2="hardAlpha" operator="out"/>
          <feColorMatrix type="matrix" values="0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0.25 0"/>
          <feBlend mode="normal" in2="BackgroundImageFix" result="effect1_dropShadow_174_86"/>
          <feBlend mode="normal" in="SourceGraphic" in2="effect1_dropShadow_174_86" result="shape"/>
        </filter>
      </defs>
      <g filter="url(#filter0_d_174_86)">
        <path d="M16.5 0L28.1913 15.75H4.80866L16.5 0Z" fill="#D9D9D9"/>
        <path d="M5.80251 15.25L16.5 0.838871L27.1975 15.25H5.80251Z" stroke="#475C46"/>
      </g>
    </svg>
    <svg width="29" height="30" viewBox="0 0 29 30" fill="none" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
      <defs>
        <filter id="filter0_d_174_87" x="0" y="0" width="29" height="30" filterUnits="userSpaceOnUse" color-interpolation-filters="sRGB">
          <feFlood flood-opacity="0" result="BackgroundImageFix"/>
          <feColorMatrix in="SourceAlpha" type="matrix" values="0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 127 0" result="hardAlpha"/>
          <feOffset dy="4"/>
          <feGaussianBlur stdDeviation="2"/>
          <feComposite in2="hardAlpha" operator="out"/>
          <feColorMatrix type="matrix" values="0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0.25 0"/>
          <feBlend mode="normal" in2="BackgroundImageFix" result="effect1_dropShadow_174_87"/>
          <feBlend mode="normal" in="SourceGraphic" in2="effect1_dropShadow_174_87" result="shape"/>
        </filter>
      </defs>
      <g filter="url(#filter0_d_174_87)">
        <rect x="4" width="21" height="22" fill="#D9D9D9"/>
        <rect x="4.5" y="0.5" width="20" height="21" stroke="#475C46"/>
      </g>
    </svg>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can adjust the CSS for the images to remove any default spacing and ensure proper alignment.

```
.heading {
    display: flex;
    align-items: center; /* Vertically center items */
}

.heading .house {
    display: grid;
    height: 25px;
    width: auto;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    gap: 0;
}

.heading .house img {
    display: block; /* Ensure images behave as blocks */
    height: 100%; /* Make images fill the height of their container */
    width: auto; /* Allow width to adjust automatically */
}
```

Comment: First problem: The images are still not aligned, the square is a few pixels to the left of the triangle. Second problem: There is still a few pixels between the triangle and the square, there shouldn't be any space like the image from the Figma file I have attached.

Answer (score 0):

I tried solving your problem using the `"display: flex"` property.

> The images that I used are different from yours that's why you will
> see a gap between the triangle image and the square image.

**Here is the link for the solution:**
[Codepen](https://codepen.io/Bhavesh_kumar_sharma/pen/ZEPOKWP?editors=1100)

Hope this helps, thanks :)

Comment: The images get aligned. But there is still some space between the triangle and the square.

Answer (score 0):

The problem here is that your icons have some space in the original file. You can check the space here with this declaration.

```css
* {
  border: 1px solid black;
 }
```

That's why you cannot control them in CSS like in the Figma file. Try exporting them without the extra space.

If you want to go with extra space, you need to do some tricks to remove the gap for your `house_top.svg` like
`margin-block-end: -10px;`

I don't recommend this, but it might be a temporary solution for a while. And you can try this method on other edges as well.

Note: You need to use the `display: grid;` with the `place-content: center;` if you want to center your items with both vertical and horizontal alignment.